# Bucket sort with different buckets size

Tags: algorithm, range

I'm trying to separate all number between 0..2^12 into 4 buckets according to a changing ranges.

For example I have [0, 1000, 2100, 4000, 4096] so I have 4 buckets: [0-1000], [1000-2100], [2100-4000], [4000-4096].

How can I build a function that puts each number in the correct number - without if's, switch cases etc.

I need something very efficient so I'm looking for a bitwise operation, or addition\subtraction and then bitwise operation.

Comment: You could have a constant 4096 element array L say, so that L[i] is the bucket number for i.

Comment: Use e.g. the two least significant bits for the bucket number: `bucket = value & 3;`

Comment: Based on the restrictions I can only assume you're writing a GPGPU kernel. If so, you'll still want a boundary check to make sure the index is not out of bounds unless the number of threads exactly matches 4096.

Comment: What does "according to a changing ranges" mean? Also, your example buckets overlap at the endpoints, which is a problem for classifying numbers.

Comment: I only have space for 4-8 buckets, as Patrick assumed I'm writing a kernel with a lot of restrictions.
Changing range means  [0, a, b, c, 4096] for every function call, the overlap only means <= or <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is in the form [0, a, b, c, 4096]. If you don't mind the precalculation you could go for the suggested array. Otherwise you could do something like this with the following assumptions:

- 32-bit signed numbers
- buckets:

  - n < a
  - a <= n < b
  - b <= n < c
  - n >= c
- buckets are labeled 0 to 3.

**3 - ((n - a) >> 31) - ((n - b) >> 31) - ((n - c) >> 31)**

The idea is that if the number is becoming negative the highest bit will be set and by shifting it 31 positions you will get 1.

You could also just add the 3 subtracted expressions to get 4 buckets, but then the 0th bucket contains the highest numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, it's seems that it can work, the order of the bucket doesn't matter as long as I know which range is in which place.